# word search puzzle generator out of bounds

Tags: puzzle

Am experiencing a problem when generating a word search puzzle of `20 x 20`. The puzzle is generated from a wordlists and words placed randomly. Problem is some words are being placed outside the grid! as seen here:

[image: Screenshot]

I have not filled the remaining buttons with random so as to get a clear picture of what is happening.
Below is the code for generating the puzzle.

```java
package wordsearch;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class PuzzleGenerator {

    Character[][] thePuzzle = null;
    int _rows;
    int _cols;

    ArrayList<String> _wordList;

    private Random random = new Random();

    public PuzzleGenerator(int Rows, int Cols, ArrayList<String> wordList) {
        thePuzzle = new Character[Rows][Cols];

        this._rows = Rows;
        this._cols = Cols;
        this._wordList = wordList;

        for (int i = 0; i < this._rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this._cols; j++) {
                thePuzzle[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }

        addWords();
    }

    public Character[][] getPuzzle(){
        return thePuzzle;
    }

    private char getCharAt(int x, int y) {
        char result = this.thePuzzle[x][y];
        return result;
    }

    private int getRows(PuzzleGenerator aPuzzle) {
        return this._rows;
    }

    private int getCols(PuzzleGenerator aPuzzle) {
        return this._cols;
    }

    private void addWords() {

        while (_wordList.size() != 0) {
            //put the first word from the list into a string
            String aWord = (String) _wordList.get(0);
            //remove the word from the list
            _wordList.remove(0);
            int numTries = 0;

            while (numTries < _rows * _cols) {
                //Choose a random location on the puzzle to start placement of word
                int startRow = random.nextInt(_rows);
                int startCol = random.nextInt(_cols);

                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, -1, 0)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, -1, 1)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, 0, 1)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, 1, 1)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, 1, 0)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, 1, -1)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, 0, -1)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (this.move(aWord, startRow, startCol, -1, -1)) {
                    break;
                }

                if (++numTries == _rows * _cols) {
                    System.err.println(aWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean move(String theWord, int startRow, int startCol, int dx, int dy) {
        boolean result = true;
        //the initial char in question for placement
        int p = 0;
        int r = startRow;
        int c = startCol;

        while (p < theWord.length()) {
            if (this.thePuzzle[startRow][startCol] == '-' || this.thePuzzle[startRow][startCol] == theWord.charAt(p)) {
                //This is the wrapping logic
                startRow = ((startRow + dx + getRows(this)) % getRows(this));
                startCol = ((startCol + dy + getCols(this)) % getCols(this));

                if (r == startRow && c == startCol) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }

                p++;
            } else {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (result == true) {
            place(theWord, r, c, dx, dy);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void place(String theWord, int startRow, int startCol, int dx, int dy) {
        //the initial char in question for placement
        int p = 0;

        while (p < theWord.length()) {

            //********COMMENTED OUT DUE TO HANGING ISSUES**************
            thePuzzle[startRow][startCol] = (char) theWord.charAt(p);

            //This is the wrapping logic
            startRow = ((startRow + dx + getRows(this)) % getRows(this));
            startCol = ((startCol + dy + getCols(this)) % getCols(this));
            p++;
        }
    }

    protected void fillPuzzle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _cols; j++) {
                if (thePuzzle[i][j] == '-') {

                    //randomly generate a capital char (65-90) for fill
                    Character aChar;
                    do {
                        aChar = (char) (random.nextInt(90) + 65);
                    } while ((int) aChar < 65 || (int) aChar > 90);

                    thePuzzle[i][j] = aChar;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void printPuzzle(String puzzleName) {
        BufferedWriter out2 = null;
        try {
            //now add the array to the file created above
            out2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(puzzleName + ".pz", true));
            for (int i = 0; i < getRows(this); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < getCols(this); j++) {
                    out2.write(thePuzzle[i][j] + " ");
                }
                out2.write("\n");
            }
            out2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void loadPuzzletoGrid() {
        //fillPuzzle();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                WordSearchPuzzle.grid[i][j].setText((thePuzzle[i][j]).toString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have a bit of code marked with the comment "This is the wrapping logic" if you don't want the words to wrap. What is the purpose of that part of the code?

Comment: That is where the problem comes in .. I borrowed this code. Please have a look at the image provided using the link above. The words should fit in the 20 x 20 grid and not appear as if they are coming from the bottom.

Comment: I've posted some code that should fix your current problem, but I'd recommend trying to read and understand the code you've borrowed and then use that knowledge to write it yourself from scratch. At the moment it looks like you've got code that isn't really designed for what you're trying to achieve, and you're likely to just keep running into more problems as you try and force this code to do what you want.

Comment: @mungaialex nice. have you finished your project? have you deployed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the code is currently causing the words to wrap when they hit the edge of the grid.

```java
// This is the wrapping logic
startRow = ((startRow + dx + getRows(this)) % getRows(this));
startCol = ((startCol + dy + getCols(this)) % getCols(this));

if (r == startRow && c == startCol) {
  result = false;
  break;
}
```

Instead you want the `move()` method to fail when it reaches the edge with something like this:

```java
startRow = startRow + dx;
startCol = startCol + dy;

if (startRow < 0 || startRow >= getRows(this) || startCol < 0 || startCol >= getCols(this)) {
  $result = false;
  break;
}
```